# Fastest way to read Azure blob files in parallel

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download the blob files from Azure using the below code

**Download Method :**

```
private static async Task<string> GetPriceString(int seriesId) {
    var maxRetries = 15;
    var storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Storage Account Connection String");
    var blob = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("Container Name")
        .GetBlockBlobReference($"{seriesId}.csv");

    var priceString = await Policy.Handle<Exception>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(maxRetries, attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(attempt * 0.5))
        .ExecuteAsync(async () => await blob.DownloadTextAsync());
    return priceString;
}
```

**Calling Code :**

```
int[] seriesIds = { 10, 100 };
List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
foreach(var seriesId in seriesIds) {
    tasks.Add(GetPriceString(seriesId));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

It works, but the problem is it takes around 30 seconds to read 100 blob files(each files size is around 200kb). Considering the size of the files, the reading speed is very slow.

Is there any better alternative to download the files in parallel, like some native Azure code instead of we manually calling it in parallel ?

Comment: A couple of things to try. 1. There's no need to get a container reference each time. Separate that out and provide it to each call to `GetPriceString` instead. 2. You're using `Polly` and are handling all exceptions. Try removing that to see if you're actually encountering exceptions which are then triggering retries.

Comment: @JohnH 1. I'll try moving it out. 2. There are no exceptions I can assure you that.

Comment: I don't think getting container reference in each loop is slowing things down. Can you tell how many cores are available to you on the machine on which this code is running?

Comment: @GauravMantri Code is running in P1V2(1 core) machine in single instance.

Comment: On a single core machine, it might be beneficial to download single blob instead of downloading multiple blobs. I read somewhere that when you launch more threads than the number of cores available, a lot of time is wasted by CPU in thread switching which actually results in operations taking longer time.

Comment: @GauravMantri - Let me check by downloading blobs serially..

Comment: I think you'll need to write your own code to call DownloadTextAsync in parallel.  I use SemaphoreSlim to help with this... if I have 100 items to download, I can tell this class to only work on say 5 at a time.

Comment: i'm willing to bet this is your bottle neck: `var blob = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("Container Name")
        .GetBlockBlobReference($"{seriesId}.csv");` why do you need to get the container name for every file individually if you already know the container?

Comment: is it possible to get the `blockblobreferences` in one call?